# mysql and do-release-upgrade

Tags: mysql, do-release-upgrade

Could someone tell me what happens to `mysql` databases when you run a `do-release-upgrade`?

When I do the dry run for `do-release-upgrade` I see that it will **uninstall** mysql client and server and install the latest version.

Does this process also drop existing databases or are they preserved?

(I do have backups but want to be aware of what lieing ahead)

Answer (score 3):

Databases are preserved if they are in the default location `/var/lib/mysql`.
 Having taken a look at the mysql-server-5.5 package there are no commands for deleting this data at all.

Generally speaking any files (usually log and data files) created in `/var` are not touched by package managers.
Apt/dpgk specifically keeps track of config files which are usually stored in `/etc` and attempts to upgrade the config files (if needed) and will remove/replace any executables/libs in `/etc`